# Disable or unset specific bash completion

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I invoked

```
complete -o default -F _foo foo
```

To enable bash auto-complete for the command `foo`. Now I want this to go away, while retaining any other completions that bash may know. How do I do this? I want a

```
complete --remove foo
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`help complete` will tell you:

```
-r  remove a completion specification for each NAME, or, if no
    NAMEs are supplied, all completion specifications
```